# How to update a field on .focusout()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like, upon loosing focus on an `<input>` field, to perform a few operations on the value of this field, including changing the content itself (so that it is uppercase)

In the following [**code**](http://codepen.io/WoJWoJ/pen/amyNJR):

**HTML**

```
<input id="name" type="text"></input>
<div id="upper"></div>
```

**JavaScript + jQuery**

```
$("#name")
  .focusout(function() {
    // get the text from the form which lost focus
    name = $("#name").val();
    // turn it into uppercase
    name = name.toUpperCase();
    // update the form and another entry
    $("#upper").text(name);
    $("#name").text(name);
  })
```

the event is correctly caught and the `<div>` is updated with the lowercase text. The content of the field, however, is not updated.

Is it possible to update the content of an `<input>` field upon leaving it?

Comment: change the `value` (`.val()`) not the text ? http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: `val()` is for form elements, `text()` is for pretty much everything else.

Comment: Not related but I want to say 2 things. First: you should define a variable before using (`var name = ...` or `let name = ...`, not `name = ...`). Second, inside the function, you can use `$(this)` instead of re-calling `$('#name')`

Comment: On more thing, an `input` is a void element, it hasn't any closing tag

Answer (score 1):

Change text() to val() for field

```
$("#name").val(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`jQuery.val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the Value, not [**`jQuery.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/), also note `this` in `handler-function` refers to `Element` on which `event` is invoked hence `this` could be used instead of `specified-selector`

You could try this simplified code:

```js
$("#name").focusout(function() {
  var name = this.value.toUpperCase();
  $("#upper").text(name);
  $(this).val(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text"></input>
<div id="upper"></div>
```